# How to save line-through effect in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a todo list extension.I have been able to save the tasks in local storage and delete them from there too.I have added a function to add a line-through effect for completed tasks on clicking a check button.
Now I am not able to figure out how to load the text with line through effect when I reload the page.

Comment: welcome! consider this - store the state and re-render when you pull the data out

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Siddharth. Have you checked the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You won't save this text-decoration in your localStorage.

You need to save a todo item as an object, like this:

```
{
   text: 'Buy milk',
   done: false
}
```

When you're rendering it, you'll display the text in the screen and use the "done" key to apply an additional class or inline style to make your content appears with the line-through style.

Remember to use [JSON.Stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) when handling objects to and from localstorage.